# Seperate liquibase file with test data per test class in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, testing, annotations, liquibase, spring-aop

I want to seperate test data for particular test. For example we have two test classes A and B they are running on diffrent data so I want to create
ATestData.xml and BTestData.xml and when test class starts it should execute ATestData.xml then rollback then start test B execute BTestData.xml.
in  Arquillian Persistence Extension there was `@UsingDataSet("datasets/users.yml")`.

I started to wrtie my own annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface LiquibaseTestDataFile {
    String value() default "";
}
```

And

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LiquibaseTestDataFileAspect {

    @Before("execution(* (@LiquibaseTestDataFile *).*(..)) || execution(@LiquibaseTestDataFile * *(..))")
    public void insertTestData(JoinPoint joinPoint){
    log.info("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Class<?> declaringClass = signature.getMethod().getDeclaringClass();
        LiquibaseTestDataFile myAnnotation = declaringClass.getAnnotation(LiquibaseTestDataFile.class);

       //TODO if null maybe on method

       //log.info(myAnnotation.value());
    }
}
```

But it not trigers when annotation is on test class.

I am using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in configuration

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TransferManagerRestApplication.class})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

in test class.

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution by using `@PostConstruct`

```
@Component
public class LiquibaseDataTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private SpringLiquibase springLiquibase;

    public void insert(String fileName){
        try {
            Connection connection = springLiquibase.getDataSource().getConnection();
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
            Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(fileName, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts(springLiquibase.getContexts()), new LabelExpression(springLiquibase.getLabels()));
        } catch (LiquibaseException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and in test class

```
@Autowired
private LiquibaseDataTestConfiguration liquibaseDataTestConfiguration;

@PostConstruct
public void initData(){
    liquibaseDataTestConfiguration.insert("liquibase/AClassTest.xml");
}
```